# The differences' between the operator "==" and "="

Tags: python

The differences' between the operator "==" and "=". When would each be used? Why would each be used?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

Comment: `=` assigns a value to a variable. `==` checks whether two variables or values are the same.

Comment: `==` is for comparing two values, `=` is used to assign a value to a variable

Comment: as said before == is for comparing and = is for assigning. This is partially because sometimes you assign things and check for others in the same line of code.

Comment: @Barmar, I think it would be appropriate to give this person feedback that SO is not the place to ask conceptual questions about programming, particularly basic ones. But I don't think it is appropriate to make a challenge like "How can you have learned . . . " -- in a way that could be interpreted as attacking the person, not the question. (We're getting a lot of really basic questions right now -- fall semester in the northern hemisphere, programming 101 is  in full swing).

Answer (score 1):

```
In python and other languages like C, 
     "=" is a assignment operator and is used to assign a value to a variable.
       Example: a=2 # the value of a is 2

whereas "==" is Comparison operator and is used to check whether 2 expressions give the same value .Equality check returns true if it succeeds and else return false.
  Example: a=2 b=3 c=2 
             a==b (#false because 2 is not equal to 3) 
               a==c (#true because 2 is equal to 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

An == expression evaluates to true, is an equality operator.
== has the value of two operands are equal make the condition or statement true.
= is an expression of assignment operator to the symbol of variables, arrays, objects.

Both operators are very important, and they work in different ways in every equivalent object. Their behavior in their operation is based on the identity of objects. Are reflation of their variables.

When using == in compares the values of two objects example having two cars from the same company and have the same identity and features and same looks.

The rule implies that the statement and condition to be trues
To use = operator is when to evaluate variables in an expression if both sides of the operator mean same or the objects are same if not same its expression will be false and if true the expressions or objects are same.

Comment: It would be great if you could format this so that is was readable.  As it stands now, this is what we call a WALL OF TEXT.  Very, very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

= is used for assignment: e.g.: apple = 'apple'.
It states what is what.
== compares one value to another. Is 5 equal to 5 should be written like this: 5 == 5