# Calculate leap year - expression must have a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to write a program that determines whether a year entered is a leap year based on three rules, all of which boil down to the remainder equaling 0.

```
int year;

cout << "Enter a year "; 
cin >> year;
cout << endl;

if (year < 1582) {
    cout << "Year must be after 1582";
}
else if (year % 4 = 0){

}
```

The condition (year % 4 = 0) gives me an error of "expression must be a modifiable lvalue". Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: == (equality) instead of = (assignment) operator. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33002475/1626280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this `year % 4 = 0` to `year % 4 == 0`

The first is an assignment, the second is a comparison.

Also, your logic is wrong. Years divisible by 100 are NOT leap years except years divisible by 400 ARE leap years.

Comment: Oh, I can't believe I made that mistake. Thank you very much. You are also correct about the other two rules.